# How to detect touch on screen in custom UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, hittest

I want to watch in my `UIView` subclass for user touches on the screen. Especially there are some additional conditions:

- the touch should not be catch by my view (for example, if user taps some button or scrolls something that action should be accepted)
- there can be multiple views which are watching for touch and they should not conflict with each other
- the approach should be as general as possible (so we can catch taps on tabbar or navigation buttons)

I can suppose to add specific fullscreen view with customized `hitTest:` method. This view has  interface to add/remove delegates for watching for touches. But this method is "hard" in coding terms and I would like to find more elegant and simpler solution.

Comment: you should be able to use the `locationInView` function on `UITouch` to tell if the touch is inside of a certain view's bounds. [UITouch locationInView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_10)

Comment: the question is not about touch position...

Comment: I know it is not, but you can use that to determine whether or not the view should handle it

Answer (score 0):

you can write touchesBegan in that UIView subclass.

> Because if it had any subview like button or scrollView, they would be first responders ,and touches on scrollView wont fire touchesBegan of your UIView subclass.
>
> And it wont conflict with other touch listeners unless the listener subView is explicitly passing that touch to your Subclass.

Comment: These subviews need to watch touches outside of their bounds too. At this moment I use additional fullscreen view with `hitTest:` but, as I mentioned, it's not elegant approach.